# Can't list file system of azure datalake with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to list the paths within a file system in Azure datalake using this code :

I'm able to retrieve ${fileSystem.name} but getting permissions denied with .listPaths()

`node:15660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RestError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.`

i'm not sure what permissions I need to provide, the service principle has owner access over the datalake storage account and also has the api permissions

[image]

the code:

```
const { DataLakeServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-file-datalake');

require('dotenv').config();

const account = 'xxx';

const defaultAzureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

const datalakeServiceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(
    `https://${account}.dfs.core.windows.net`,
    defaultAzureCredential
);

async function main() {
    let i = 1;
    let iter = await datalakeServiceClient.listFileSystems();

    for await (const fileSystem of iter) {
        console.log(`File system ${i++}: ${fileSystem.name} `);
        const fileSystemClient = datalakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient(fileSystem.name);
        let iter = await fileSystemClient.listPaths();
        for await (const path of iter) {
            console.log(`Path ${i}: ${path.name}, is directory: ${path.isDirectory}`);
        }

    }
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue, navigate to your data lake gen2 storage account in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> assign a `Storage Blob Data Owner` role to your service principal.

[image]

Then the code works fine:

[image]