# How to generate user delegation SAS for Azure Storage using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-sdk

I'm trying to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage. What I've done so far:

```
npm i @azure/identity @azure/storage-blob
```

Generate SAS query parameters with a user delegation key:

```
async function generateSas() {
    const startDate = new Date();
    const expiryDate = new Date();
    startDate.setTime(startDate.getTime() - 100 * 60 * 1000);
    expiryDate.setTime(expiryDate.getTime() + 100 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(STORAGE, credential);
    const key = await blobServiceClient.getUserDelegationKey(startDate, expiryDate);

    return generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
        containerName: CONTAINER,
        startsOn: startDate,
        expiresOn : expiryDate,
        permissions: ContainerSASPermissions.parse('rwl'),
    }, key, ACCOUNT).toString();
}
```

Use the generated SAS to upload

```
async function upload(sasToken: string) {
    const blobClient = new BlockBlobClient(
      `https://${ACCOUNT}.blob.core.windows.net/${CONTAINER}/test.json?${sasToken}`);
    const content = 'some content';
    const response = await blobClient.upload(content, content.length);
}
```

Before I run this, I do `az login` with my account.

The error:

```
(node:19584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RestError: This request is not authorized to perform 
this operation using this permission.
```

If I copy a SAS from **Azure Storage Explorer** with the same login, the code works! So I assume that there is some way to retrieve a valid SAS for my account.

Answer (score 2):

*I suspect that this is a **permission issue**.*

After analyzing [Can't list file system of azure datalake with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61662089/cant-list-file-system-of-azure-datalake-with-javascript) and [ManagedIdentityCredential failed when used to list blob containers #5539](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/5539) issues closely, I think that the `Owner` role is not sufficient for uploading blobs inside your blob storage account. You'll have to use one of the `Storage Blob Data *` roles (like `Storage Blob Data Owner` before you can upload blobs.

So, try adding `Storage Blob Data Owner` role to your intended user and try running the code again.

Comment: But why can I upload with Azure Storage Explorer. The Explorer uses the same login as my little program. Maybe the access_token from `DefaultAzureCredential` and `az login` is missing something...?

Comment: Do you have this permission assigned? Check out this MS Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet#assign-azure-roles-for-access-to-data . Also, check if you are setting permissions like `SetPermissions` in the js code : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet#get-a-user-delegation-sas-for-a-blob

Comment: No. But I didn't change any roles, because that's the whole motivation of the question: I don't WANT to change roles. And there has to be a way, because it works in Storage Explorer. Azure Storage Explorer knows how to generate a SAS for my user without requiring any special roles on it. But thanks for asking again ;)

Comment: Can you try using Https for it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-user-delegation-key#authorization?

Comment: according to the doc, `Owner` role is not enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-user-delegation-sas#assign-permissions-with-rbac

The following roles should work: 
    Contributor,
    Storage Account Contributor,
    Storage Blob Data Contributor,
    Storage Blob Data Owner,
    Storage Blob Data Reader, and
    Storage Blob Delegator.

The SAS you copied from Azure Storage Explorer is secured with account key it's different from a user delegation SAS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#service-sas